# Python SQL query with variables from function

Tags: python, mysql, sql

How can I get variable from function to use it in a SQL query ?

Example: I have function in Python :

```
def week(monday, friday)
     monday = '2015-12-14'
     friday = '2015-12-18'
     ...[some other code]...
     mysql.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE (data BETWEEN Date(%s) AND Date(%s)) ''', [monday,friday,])
     ...[some other code]...
```

It works correct but there is fixed date in this function `monday = '2015-12-14'`

This one generates an error :

(just disabled variable declaration because I would like to get it from function)

```
def week(monday, friday)
    #monday = '2015-12-14'
    #friday = '2015-12-18'
     ...
     mysql.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE (data BETWEEN Date(%s) AND Date(%s)) ''', [monday,friday,])

...[some other code]...
week('2015-12-14', '2015-12-18')
```

> Warning: Incorrect datetime value:'1'

Comment: try to print the monday and friday variables before the query and check what data are they having? If it returns the python date object then you will have to convert them to iso format string and then pass.

Comment: try debugging by storing the monday and friday values in variables and printing them and type.

Comment: Is there a better way (instead using %s ) to prevent SQL-Injection ?

Comment: There's no SQL injection here. The query is parameterised correctly, assuming that `%s` is a valid placeholder. Which mysql dbapi are you using?

Comment: You've updated your question to state that it is now working. What was wrong?

Comment: There problem was : wrong variable declaration in main program. This function is working correctly. Thank you

Comment: If you solved your problem, please don't edit your question. Instead, post an answer yourself.